# Is there a way to use mathmode expressions inside the grammar environment?

Tags: errors, compiling, syntax

I'm trying to write the grammar of FOL in BNF using the `syntax` package, but every time I use a logical symbol or a mathmode command (ex. \neg, \land, \mathbb{}, etc.) I get an error. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\usepackage{syntax}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

    \begin{grammar}
        <formula> ::= <formula> <connective> <formula>
        \alt `\neg' <formula> 
        \alt <quantifier> <variable> `(' <formula> `)'
    \end{grammar}
```

returns the error

```
Missing $ inserted. \alt `\neg
Extra }, or forgotten $. \alt `\neg'
Missing $ inserted. \alt `\neg'
Missing } inserted. \alt `\neg'
```

I've tried using $...$ and ${...}$, but I still get an error.

Other errors are usually

`\< command > allowed only in math mode.`

Is there a way to use mathmode inside the `grammar` environment?

Comment: I can't test but IIRC `syntax` treats `$` literally. Maybe you could try with `\(\neg\)`.

Comment: @campa Perfect! That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `grammar` environment the characters `` ` ``, `<`, and `"` are  active in order to obtain the following appearance

[image]

Quoting from the `syntax` manual

> Within one of these abbreviated forms, text is treated more-or-less verbatim:
>
> - Any `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `{`, `}`, `~` or `#` characters are treated literally: their normal
>     special meanings are ignored.
> - Other special characters, with the exception of `\`, are also treated literally: [...]

In this case, the LaTeX way of making inline math, namely `\(...\)`, comes to rescue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
    <formula> ::= <formula> <connective> <formula>
    \alt `\(\neg\)' <formula> 
    \alt <quantifier> <variable> `(' <formula> `)'
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

[image]